# what is the type of request and response object generated by container?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

As it is written in the book when a request comes for a `Servlet`, a request and response object is generated by the container and put into the service method as an argument.

```
HttpServletRequest
HttpServletResponse
ServletRequest
ServletResponse
```

are `Interface` so they can't be instantiated.

So

1. what is the type of the object?
2. What information does the request and response method contains?
3. How does the container know it is a get or post request?

Answer (score 0):

1. Whatever type the container chooses to instantiate, conforming to the interfaces you list.
2. Whatever information the interface exposes, plus whatever the implementation provides. To access non-interface functionality you must cast, of course.
3. ... By looking at the request. Read the HTTP spec.

Comment: Can U explain the 3rd point or give any link where I can some study.

Comment: How the container chose the type? means the type to instantiate.

Comment: @user3773682 The container can choose the type to instantiate based on whatever criteria it wants. HTTP requests, naturally, should probably instantiate something that implements `HttpServlet`-related interfaces. The third point: HTTP requests include the request type, that's kind of the point of HTTP requests and the HTTP verbs (GET, POST, DELETE, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You should review the [Java EE Tutorial - Chapter 15 Java Servlet Technology](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html) and remember that JSP(s) are compiled into Servlet(s). For web based requests,

1. The container's implementation of the interface.
2. See the [`ServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html) and [`ServletRepsonse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html) Javadocs.
3. By calling the [`Servlet.service(request, response)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html#service%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29), the container has the default behavior of parsing the request and calling `doGet()` or `doPost()` (or one of the other methods from `Servlet`).

Answer (score 0):

1. You may need to look into [ServletResponseWrapper, HttpServletResponseWrapper, ServletRequestWrapper & HttpServletRequestWrapper](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html) under package **javax.servlet.http**. In addition, the web container implementation may subclass those wrapper classes or implement those interfaces
2. And look into `ServletRequest` and `ServletResponse` interface in above api doc.
3. Look into `service()` method as explained in @Elliott Frisch's answer.